# ESlint disable rule for specific file endings using eslintrc

Tags: jestjs, eslint, cypress, file-extension, eslintrc

I'm testing my app with Jest and Cypress using TypeScript. The Jest files end in `.test.ts`, while the Cypress test files end in `.spec.ts`. I use the [Jest ESLint plugin](https://github.com/jest-community/eslint-plugin-jest), which comes with the [`expect-expect`](https://github.com/jest-community/eslint-plugin-jest/blob/master/docs/rules/expect-expect.md) rule. Many Cypress tests don't contain an `expect`.

How can I disable this rule for files ending in `.spec.ts`? Is it possible to disable rules for specific file extenions in the `.eslintrc.json`? (I want to avoid having to write a comment in each of the `.spec.ts` files.)

**EDIT:** I know that I could add `"cy.*"` to the `"assertFunctionNames"`, but there are other rules that I need to disable for `.spec` files, too, such as `valid-expect` and `valid-expect-in-promise`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `override` property in `.eslintrc` file. [Using configuration files to disable for a group of files](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#using-configuration-files-1)

So what you want is to disable `jest/expect-expect` rule for all files with the extension `.spec.ts`, you need to add this in your `.eslintrc` file.

```
{
  "rules": {...},
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.spec.ts"],
      "rules": {
        "jest/expect-expect": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can we disable all of jest rules just for that file (w/o listing individually)?